# binary coded decimals (BCD) put into a byte in C#

Tags: tcp, byte, bcd

I'm working on implementing a protocol tha tells me to put decimals from 0 to 160 into a single byte.
I assume, since it doesn't specify what sort of BCD it wants, that I am to put one digit into the lower nibble and the other decimal into the higher nibble. Meaning I get 1 byte with a two-digit decimal.
But how would any larger value fit into a single byte? For example 160?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it is referring to "Densely Packed Decimal" my experience with BCD in a telecommunications CDR format is as you describe, where 99 is the highest decimal that can be encoded in a single byte. But a quick Wikipedia search turned up DPD.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densely_Packed_Decimal